# SQL Server table indexing when a query has group by and order by clauses

Tags: sql-server, database-indexes

Would be some obvious indexes that should be on the below table `Users` that would optimize for the below query?

I can see the need for indexes, but not sure how to combine indexes would GROUP BY and ORDER BY are included.

The columns I see are:

1. Status
2. CreatedDate
3. Region, LocationId

Below is the query:

```
SELECT
  u.UserId,
  u.LocationId,
  others.ArchiveCount
FROM Users u
  OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1
      CASE WHEN u2.Status = 'ARCHIVED' THEN
        1
      ELSE 
        0
      END as ArchiveCount
    FROM Users u2
    WHERE u2.UserId = u.UserId
    ORDER BY u2.CreatedDate desc
  ) others
GROUP BY u.RegionId, u.LocationId, others.ArchiveCount
ORDER BY u.RegionId, u.LocationId, others.ArchiveCount
```

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of the OUTER APPLY? Is UserId a primary key? Or are there multiple rows with the same UserId? Assuming the latter, what IS the primary key? And do you have an index on UserId, CreatedDate DESC? Because that's one index you'll want. Look at the plan and see if there's a sort for that inner select. As for the outer, an index that matches your groupby/orderby columns as the key may help. Again, you'd have to look to the plan to see if it gets used. Try it.

Comment: If that's the case, what is that OUTER APPLY for? Because that join can only ever join a single row to itself, which means it's completely wasted effort. Help me understand what the intent is there, because it seems like a complete waste to me unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Sorry UserID is not the PK.  There can be multiple UserId's in that table.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a covering index (kitchen sink):

```
CREATE INDEX IX_CoveringIndex1 ON Users (UserId)
INCLUDE (
    RegionId
    , LocationId
    , CreatedDate
    , [Status]
    )
GO
```